# SQL - order by statement

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I've got tables like:

```
table A
id name   email
1  test1  ex@ex.com
2  test2  ex@ex.com
3  test3  ex@ex.com
4  test4   ....
5  test5   ....

table B
id catA    catB   year member 
1  false   true   2011  2
2  true    false  2011  3
3  fals    true   2010  5
```

And i want to get every row in table A and sort it by following:

```
FIRST, get user 2 (current year, based on table B)
SECOND, get user 3 (current year, based on table B)
after that get users that is in table B
after that get all other users.
```

I know that i can have specific sql for getting the first two users, and the just the 
rest. But shouldnt i be able to get them all with a nice ORDER by statement? Like limiting the first order statement to just affect the first row...

Comment: If you've got an answer to your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select A.id, A.name, A.email, B.catA, B.catB, B.year
from A
join B on A.id = B.member
ORDER BY B.year DESC, (B.member IS NOT NULL) DESC
```

First sort all results by the year field in table B, which gets you 2011, 2010, etc... Any members who are NOT listed in table B will have a null year and sort to the bottom of the list. Next sort by B.member not being null - mysql will coerce this boolean result into an integer 1 or 0, which can be sorted, So sort descending to make all the 1's (not null B.members) sort first.

Comment: Allmost got it:
     ORDER BY (tableb.year IS NULL) ASC,(tableb.member IS NOT NULL)     DESC.

Gets it allmost correct, the problem now is that i want to get B.catA first, then B.catB. And also if its possible, i only want the latest in catA and catB, after that the order doesnt matter...

Comment: Fixed it:
ORDER BY(CASE tableB.year WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC,tableA.id desc;

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sorting rules:

```
after that get users that is in table B
after that get all other users.
```

I assume that there are some users in table A that do not exist in B, so you'd want to use a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.email
    FROM a
        LEFT JOIN b
           ON a.id = b.member
    ORDER BY ISNULL(b.year), b.year DESC, a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always 'order by', however grotesquely complicated your select is, buy putting the data-gathering elements into a derived table, selecting from it, and ordering by the results. Something like...

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
    FROM
        (SELECT 1 as col1,
                col2,
                ' ' AS col3
             FROM blah...blah...blah
           UNION
         SELECT 2 AS col1
                col2,
                col3
             FROM blah...blah...blah
           UNION
         and so on) myderivedtable
    ORDER BY col1,
             col2,
             col3
```

You just have to make sure all the columns you are selecting in each of the queries come out the same, or cope with a NULL value otherwise.